# How can I access private field in enclosing class when creating instance with overridden method in static factory method?

Tags: java

I'm not sure what is going on here. The line causing the error is inside an implementation of an object of type Printer which has a field named 'string'. The whole thing is contained inside the abstract class named 'Printer'. How can I achieve what I want while keeping the 'string'-field private?

```
public abstract class Printer {

   static Printer blahPrinter(){
      Printer blahPrinter =  new Printer("blah") {
         @Override
         void printString() {
            System.out.println(this.string); //Here is the error: "string has private access in Printer"
         }
      };
      System.out.println(blahPrinter.string); //No error on this line
      return blahPrinter;
  }

  private final String string;  //Compiles and works as expected if I use a more visible access modifier

  public Printer(String string) {
     this.string = "I say " + string;
  }

  abstract void printString();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     final Printer blahPrinter = Printer.blahPrinter();
     blahPrinter.printString();
  }

}
```

Comment: I can use getters, but they would need a more visible access modifier too. In my real code (this is obviously just an example) different types of implementations need access to fields in the abstract class, but no one else does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by saying:

```
System.out.println(super.string);
```

The thing is that private members are not inherited by subclasses, although they are accessible within the whole body of the top-level class in which the private members are declared. As such, the error message from the compiler is confusing (and may say "wrong").

See [JLS 6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) on accessibility:

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then
>   access is permitted if and only if it occurs **within the body of the
>   top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member** or
>   constructor.

This is the case here, since you're accessing the private member from within the body of `Printer`, which encloses the declaration.

But [JLS section 8.2 "class members"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2) has the rules on inheritance:

> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by
>   subclasses of that class.

So you can't say `this.string`, since the field `string` is not present on the anonymous subclass of `Printer` in which your `printString` method resides.

By explicitly referring to `super` (or using the typecast in Hero's answer), you make clear that you don't want to access the field in the subclass but from the superclass.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm so used to thinking that if it's inside the curly braces of the class, I can read privates...

Answer (score 1):

In your anonymous subclass you can replace `this.string` by `((Printer) this).string` or `super.string`.

Comment: That worked. But strange that compiler can't figure it out by itself. The code is within "new Printer(..){....". Anyway, thanks!